# UITableView is Looping Through Cells (That I Don't Want it to)

Tags: ios, swift, loops, tableview, master-detail

I'm working on a master-detail application wherein I use custom prototype cells with images and a few other details to catalog things. the system is working very well, until you make more than eight cells. After you get to that point, the app begins to 'loop through' the cells. I don't know if the cells are being duplicated or just re-displayed, but if you delete neighbouring cells forcing them to become different than eight cells apart, sometimes the other clone will disappear. It seems like they're entangled or something.

Custom Cell Class:

```
import UIKit

class UITableViewToolCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sellerImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLocation: UILabel!

var name = "New Item"
var location = "Unknown"
var soldBy = "nil"
var category = "nil"
var thumbnail = "nil"
var information = "Information Not Available"

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    name += " \(arc4random_uniform(5000))"
    itemTitle.text = name
    itemLocation.text = location
    sellerImage.image = UIImage(named: soldBy)
    categoryImage.image = UIImage(named: category)

    let image : UIImageView = thumbnailImage
    image.layer.borderWidth=2.0
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height/2
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.image = UIImage(named: thumbnail)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

MasterViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController , UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = [UITableViewToolCell]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    tableView.rowHeight = 111
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: "insertNewObject:")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green: 0.18, blue: 0.18, alpha: 1.0)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)]
    addButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    let t = UITableViewToolCell()
    objects.insert(t, atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController

            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ToolCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewToolCell
    objects[indexPath.row] = cell
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        objects.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

}

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement in you custom cell:

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    itemTitle.text = ""
    //... and so on
}
```

Just clean up the field of your cell inside this method.

Comment: This seemed to be working, but my problem still exists : If I do this, every time a cell is scrolled beneath the bottom of the screen, It calls this function and clears all of it's properties so it's name, icon, and everything else are replaced with defaults. All I am doing in the method is resetting the variables to their initial value and calling awakefromnib() to push the variables into their objects.